# First attempt using MiKTeX fails

Tags: miktex

I am new to MikTex, but have some experience with Latex.

Installed Miktex for windows from here https://miktex.org/download. Selected all default installation options.

On starting TeXWorks, selected "New from template...", selected "Basic Article" (make no change to template)

Press Typeset(green play button). Get an error dialog: "invalid stoi argument".

Looks like a package problem as next dialog is "required file could not  be found: geometry.sty"

The "package will be installed for:" drop down is empty. Seems suspicious

Click install in package dialog, invited to select a package source, I did so (tried a few different repos). Another odd thing, the package information dialog does not remember which source I selected on the previous attempt. But I can click "Change" and select a source.

Then get: "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed." in console.

Here is the log output

```
2021-02-02 16:55:39,055Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3464) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-pdftex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex untitled-2.tex
2021-02-02 16:55:39,063Z WARN  miktex-pdftex - security risk: running with elevated privileges
2021-02-02 16:55:39,071Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - allowing known shell commands
2021-02-02 16:55:46,194Z INFO  miktex-pdftex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories?&releaseState=Stable
2021-02-02 16:55:49,386Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - installing package geometry triggered by tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
2021-02-02 16:55:49,403Z INFO  miktex-pdftex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories/db90da458ceeb4a0f389b9d21de4aa96
2021-02-02 16:55:49,619Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2021-02-02 16:55:49,619Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: installation directory: C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2021-02-02 16:55:49,619Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository: ftp://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2021-02-02 16:55:49,622Z FATAL miktex-pdftex - invalid stoi argument
2021-02-02 16:55:49,622Z INFO  miktex-pdftex - this process (3464) finishes with exit code 1
```

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you choose a packages repository to download from? You can choose one from MiKTeX Settings, ‘General’ tab.

Comment: yes. the repo highlighted in the screenshot is also sleected in MikTeX/Settings/General. and I have tried a few different repos to see if the source was the problem

Comment: Did you try installing directly from MiKTeX Package Manager?

Comment: When you install MikTeX it asks whether to auto install packages, ask first, or no auto install.  I don't know about TeXWorks, but my editor cannot handle the "ask first" option.  See the MikTeX console, settings->general options.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that worked for me. Thanks. If you write it as an answer, Ill mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some editors cannot handle the "ask me" option for auto loading packages.  Use the MikTeX console settings->general to choose another option.